# Extract frame from multi page tiff - c#

Tags: c#

Have a multi page tiff and I want to extract page[n]/frame[n] from this Tiff file and save it.

If my multi page tiff has 3 frames, after I extract one page/frame - I want to be left with

1 image having 2 pages/frames and

1 image having only 1 page/frame.

Answer (score 6):

Here is some code to save the last Frame in a multi-frame tiff to a single page tiff file.
(In order to use this code you need to add a reference to the PresentationCore.dll).

```
Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(imageFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
        memstream.SetLength(imageStreamSource.Length);
        imageStreamSource.Read(memstream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)imageStreamSource.Length);
        imageStreamSource.Close();

        BitmapDecoder decoder = TiffBitmapDecoder.Create(memstream,BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,BitmapCacheOption.Default);

        Int32 frameCount = decoder.Frames.Count;

        BitmapFrame imageFrame = decoder.Frames[0];

        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(imageFrame);
        encoder.Save(output);

        FileStream outStream = File.OpenWrite("Image.Tiff");
        output.WriteTo(outStream);
        outStream.Flush();
        outStream.Close();
        output.Flush();
        output.Close();
```

Comment: In order to use this code you need to add a reference to the PresentationCore.dll which can be found in your '[Program Files]/Reference Assemblies' folder. This assembly contains the 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging' namespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void SaveFrame(string path, int frameIndex, string toPath)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            BitmapDecoder dec = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache, BitmapCacheOption.None);
            BitmapEncoder enc = BitmapEncoder.Create(dec.CodecInfo.ContainerFormat);

            enc.Frames.Add(dec.Frames[frameIndex]);

            using (FileStream tmpStream = new FileStream(toPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                enc.Save(tmpStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php), extracting pages is a simple one-liner:

```
convert input.tif[page] output.tif
```

To extract a range of pages, replace `[page]` with `[frompage-topage]`. It's important to note that *page count start from zero*.

In your case, you'd have to run the command twice, but ImageMagick is so powerful I bet there is another one-line command that does the split just the way you want.

Never used C#, so I don't know whether or not this can be used inside your code.