# Separating Multi-Page Tiffs into separate pages

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Currently I am using .NET to break apart multi-page tiffs into separate jpeg/pngs. The process on its own is perfectly fine. But after few weeks, I notice one big flaw in the page sizes. Each page I separate is the same (width/height NOT FILE SIZE) as the whole TIFF document combined. When the TIFF is displayed, this creates a massive black spot on the right/bottom of the image. This is a very big flaw as I can't determine the physical dimensions of each page as I am separating them. If I know ahead of time, I can at least write up some kind of cropping mechanism. Any advise is appreciated.

```
        System.IO.Stream s =
            new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageData);

        System.Drawing.Image i =
            System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s);

        int NumberOfFrames = i.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);

        List<byte[]> imageCollection = new List<byte[]>();

        for (int f = 0; f < NumberOfFrames; f++)
        {
            i.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, f);

            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(i.Width, i.Height);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Default;
            g.DrawImageUnscaled(i, 0, 0);
            g.Dispose();
           imageCollection.Add((byte[])System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(b).ConvertTo(b, typeof(byte[])));
        }

        return imageCollection;
```

Comment: Would a TiffBitmapDecoder help? There's an example of using it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398881/extract-frame-from-multi-page-tiff-c-sharp

Comment: There shouldn't be any "drawing" happening for what you are trying to do. The raw data can be repackaged into individual files without decoding/drawing/re-encoding it. This is probably a limitation of the high level language you're using. Since you have no need for any codecs, and you don't need to manipulate the TIFF tags, simply walk the IFD list and break apart the file, and reset the offsets of each tag (since they're not relative) in the new file.

Comment: I just downloaded the LibTiff.NET from bitmiracle.com. It looks like it has the functionality I am looking for. Lets see how it goes. I might have to scratch the above mess and just use LibTiff if everything works. Will keep posted.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398881/extract-frame-from-multi-page-tiff-c-sharp). I did want to mention I tried it and it worked out perfectly. All the base issues that I faced is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the problem description, but it sounds like the pages you are breaking apart have alpha channel data in them. It sounds like you're not handling that correctly, so the resultant bitmap shows a default black color where it should be transparent.

If that's the case, then:

1) Fix the extractor to handle alpha channel correctly

2) Write a method that finds the smallest bounding box that minimizes the amount of alpha in the box, then crop the image to that box.